# pre-filling address fields in paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

I have been creating a website for a non-profit, and they asked me to create a DONATE page.  I did, and I collect various fields such as name, phone, address etc on that page to store in a database.  But I'm not willing to collect credit cards, due to security issues, even though I have SSL encryption.  So I route the viewer to paypal, sending various hidden fields with information.  That works fine.
Unfortunately, the leader of the non-profit does not want people to go through the hassle of signing up for paypal.  Is there anyway to pre-fill the fields in the paypal page for a "guest signup"?  I see when I get to the page that it asks for information that I've already asked for.
Maybe if its all pre-filled, the owner of the non-profit will tolerate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside